# Find $\exp\bigg[t\left ( \begin{matrix} -1& 1 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{matrix} \right )\bigg]$ by definition

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Find $\exp\bigg[t\left ( \begin{matrix}
    -1& 1 \\
    0 & -1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right )\bigg]$ **by definition**

Denote $A=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    -1& 1 \\
    0 & -1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right )$

I find out that
$$A^n=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    -1& n \\
    0 & -1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that } n\mod 2 =1$$

$$A^n=\left ( \begin{matrix}
    1& -n \\
    0 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that } n\mod 2 =0$$

Denote $k=2n,j=2n+1$.

$e^{tA}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}A^k + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{t^j}{j!}A^j$

I got a bit confused how to find $e^{tA}$ **by definition**

Thanks !

Comment: The sum over $j$ and $k$ are over the same things, they should be divided into a sum over evens and odds instead. That way you can use the first $A^n$ equation for one of the terms and the second for the other term.

Comment: From what you've done [after you make @Andrei's correction]  you should be able to find the four entries of $e^{tA}$: the $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ entries are $e^{-t}$, the $(2,1)$ entry is $0$ - I leave you to add up the series for the $(1,2)$ entry.

Comment: Your expressions for $A^n$ are wrong. Take for example $n=1$ or $n=2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your insight, it may be more helpful to rewrite the powers of $A$ (you made a slight error) as

$$A^n = (-1)^n \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!}A^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-t)^n}{n!} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{(-t)^n}{n!} & -\frac{(-t)^n}{(n-1)!} \\ 0 & \frac{(-t)^n}{n!} \end{pmatrix}$$

Then you can compute these sums component-wise using the Taylor expansion for $e$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,$$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}(-1)^n&(-1)^{n-1}n\\0&(-1)^n\end{bmatrix}.$$So,$$(tA)^n=\begin{bmatrix}(-1)^nt^n&(-1)^{n-1}nt^n\\0&(-1)^nt^n\end{bmatrix},$$and therefore\begin{align}\exp(tA)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\begin{bmatrix}(-1)^nt^n&(-1)^{n-1}nt^n\\0&(-1)^nt^n\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t}&te^{-t}\\0&e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}